# Python pickle adds first double value instead of single

Tags: python, pickle

This is the version of rock paper scissors game but I dont seem to find the solution to why it always adds double values to the first score that you get. For example if I play two games in a row it prints out double the amount of the first score and single amount of the second score and stores both of them inside the pickle.

```
import pickle
import random

rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

CHOICES = '''
1 - Play
2 - Statistic
3 - Quit'''


STATISTIC = '''
1 - This game results
2 - History of all results
3 - Quit
'''


victory, defeat, draw = [0, 0, 0]
victory_all, defeat_all, draw_all = [0, 0, 0]
gestures = [rock, paper, scissors]

while True:
    choice = input(CHOICES)

    if choice == "1":
        try:
            with open("rezultatai46.pkl", "rb") as file_pickle:
                victory_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
                defeat_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
                draw_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open("rezultatai46.pkl", "wb") as file_pickle:
                storage = victory_all, defeat_all, draw_all
                pickle.dumps(victory_all)
                pickle.dumps(defeat_all)
                pickle.dumps(draw_all)

        print('\nWelcome to ROCK PAPER SCISSORS game!\n')
        player_choice = int(input("Your choice:\n0 - Rock\n1 - Paper\n2 - Scissors\n"))
        computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)

        if player_choice >= 3 or computer_choice < 0:
            print("Character error, you lose!")
        else:
            print("Your choice:")
            print(gestures[player_choice])
            print("Computer choice:")
            print(gestures[computer_choice])

        if player_choice == 0 and computer_choice == 2:
            victory += 1
            print("Tu laimėjai!")

        elif computer_choice == 0 and player_choice == 2:
            defeat += 1
            print("Tu pralaimėjai!")

        elif computer_choice > player_choice:
            computer_choice += 1
            print("Tu pralaimėjai!")

        elif player_choice > computer_choice:
            victory += 1
            print("Tu laimėjai!")

        elif computer_choice == player_choice:
            draw += 1
            print("Lygiosios")

        with open("rezultatai46.pkl", "wb") as file_pickle:
            storage = victory_all, defeat_all, draw_all
            victory_all = (victory_all + victory)
            defeat_all = (defeat_all + defeat)
            draw_all = (draw_all + draw)
            pickle.dump(victory_all, file_pickle)
            pickle.dump(defeat_all, file_pickle)
            pickle.dump(draw_all, file_pickle)

    elif choice == "2":

        while True:
            choice = input(STATISTIC)
            if choice == "1":
                print(f"This game session:\nWon: {victory}\n"
                      f"Lost: {defeat}\nDraaw: {draw}")

            elif choice == "2":

                with open("rezultatai46.pkl", "rb") as file_pickle:
                    victory_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
                    defeat_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
                    draw_all = pickle.load(file_pickle)
                    print("Won in total:", victory_all)
                    print("Lost in total:", defeat_all)
                    print("Draw in total:", draw_all)
                    games_all = (victory_all + defeat_all + draw_all)
                    victory_percentage = ((victory_all / games_all) * 100)
                    print("Laimėjimai procentais: ", round(victory_percentage), "%")

            elif choice == "3":
                break

    elif choice == "3":
        print("Iki susitikimo!")
        break
    else:
        print("Netinkamas pasirinkimas")
```

Comment: The pickle file does not get updated after every new start. The previously saved file is being read and the new results are added to it. Try saving the result file after every `statistics-history of all results` data is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you have an error in this part:

```
        elif computer_choice > player_choice:
            computer_choice += 1
            print("Tu pralaimėjai!")
```

It should be adding to `defeat`, not `computer_choice`. That is the cause of seem different behaviors for wins and losses.

Second: you are counting the current score to variables `victory, defeat, draw`, since program start, and *always* adding the total local score to the total scores when pickling - but then you update again the total score when starting the next round.

Bear with me:

round 1:
total_victory = 0
victory = 0

Player wins:
victory = 1, total_victory += victory -> 1 and it is saved

round 2 starts at:
victory = 1
total_victory = 1

Player wins:
victory = 2
total_victory += victory -> 3

Round 3 starts at:
victory = 2
total_victory = 3
And after another win goes to:
victory = 3
total_victory += victory -> 6

---

The logic of this program is nice, and it can be seem you are being creative as you learn - which is great. But the fact you did not follow more usual patterns make it hard to fix without re-writting a significant part of your code.

So, as I pointed the error, I will leave it up to you to think how to fix it.
Probably the easier way is *always* adding "1" to total_victory, etc... as you add "1" to "victory", and never try to add "total_victory + victory" (and counterparts).

Comment: now, as for hints to make this all easier: you might want to keep your scores in a dicitionary, instead of independent variables - and it can then be stored in disk either as pikler or as json, which is human-readable.  
Another tip: now study functions, and try to break your program in several functions, instead of a single script inside a "while"  loop